# Why are these two distance-conversion methods creating different output?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, numbers, nested-loops, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to clean up some code I wrote. The code is used to convert distance units; for example, meters to kilometers or parsecs to AU. In the code below, there are two implementations; the first implementation is my failed attempt to clean up the code in the second implementation. The second implementation works correctly, but I'm trying to use less repetition in my code while still being readable.

In the code below, only distance units are converted (I plan to add other types of unit conversions later). First, the units are scaled in size relative to one meter. From this, all other unit conversions are determined (since `AU --> m` conversions will be `1000` times greater than `AU --> km` conversions, where `1000` is the size of `1 km / 1 m`.

```
class UnitConversions():

    def __init__(self):
        self.base_units = ('m', 'km', 'AU', 'LY', 'pc')
        self.base_values = (1, 1000, 1.496e11, 9.461e15, 3.086e16)

    @property
    def first_distance_conversion_factors(self):
        res = {}
        res['m'] = dict(zip(self.base_units, self.base_values))
        for outer_key in self.base_units:
            if outer_key != 'm':
                res[outer_key] = {inner_key : value / res['m'][inner_key] for inner_key, value in res['m'].items()}
        return res

    @property
    def second_distance_conversion_factors(self):
        """ """
        res = {}
        res['m'] = {'m' : 1, 'km' : 1000, 'AU' : 1.496e11, 'LY' : 9.461e15, 'pc' : 3.086e16}
        res['km'] = {key : value / res['m']['km'] for key, value in res['m'].items()}
        res['AU'] = {key : value / res['m']['AU'] for key, value in res['m'].items()}
        res['LY'] = {key : value / res['m']['LY'] for key, value in res['m'].items()}
        res['pc'] = {key : value / res['m']['pc'] for key, value in res['m'].items()}
        return res

    def first_convert_distance(self, distance, original_unit, prime_unit='m'):
        """ """
        conversion_factor = self.first_distance_conversion_factors[prime_unit][original_unit]
        return distance * conversion_factor

    def second_convert_distance(self, distance, original_unit, prime_unit='m'):
        """ """
        conversion_factor = self.second_distance_conversion_factors[prime_unit][original_unit]
        return distance * conversion_factor

UC = UnitConversions()
distance = 5

for original_unit in UC.base_units:
    for prime_unit in UC.base_units:
        # res = UC.first_convert_distance(distance, original_unit, prime_unit)
        res = UC.second_convert_distance(distance, original_unit, prime_unit)
        print('\n {} {} = {} {}'.format(distance, original_unit, res, prime_unit))
```

I have commented out the first method since it does not work. Running the code above (using the second method) prints the following output:

```
 5 m = 5 m

 5 m = 0.005 km

 5 m = 3.342245989304813e-11 AU

 5 m = 5.284853609555015e-16 LY

 5 m = 1.6202203499675955e-16 pc

 5 km = 5000 m

 5 km = 5.0 km

 5 km = 3.342245989304813e-08 AU

 5 km = 5.284853609555016e-13 LY

 5 km = 1.6202203499675955e-13 pc

 5 AU = 748000000000.0 m

 5 AU = 748000000.0 km

 5 AU = 5.0 AU

 5 AU = 7.906140999894303e-05 LY

 5 AU = 2.4238496435515228e-05 pc

 5 LY = 4.7305e+16 m

 5 LY = 47305000000000.0 km

 5 LY = 316209.89304812835 AU

 5 LY = 5.0 LY

 5 LY = 1.5328904731043422 pc

 5 pc = 1.543e+17 m

 5 pc = 154300000000000.0 km

 5 pc = 1031417.1122994652 AU

 5 pc = 16.309058239086777 LY

 5 pc = 5.0 pc
```

If one runs the first method (the incorrect method), then the following output is printed:

```
 5 m = 5 m

 5 m = 5.0 km

 5 m = 5.0 AU

 5 m = 5.0 LY

 5 m = 5.0 pc

 5 km = 5000 m

 5 km = 5.0 km

 5 km = 5.0 AU

 5 km = 5.0 LY

 5 km = 5.0 pc

 5 AU = 748000000000.0 m

 5 AU = 5.0 km

 5 AU = 5.0 AU

 5 AU = 5.0 LY

 5 AU = 5.0 pc

 5 LY = 4.7305e+16 m

 5 LY = 5.0 km

 5 LY = 5.0 AU

 5 LY = 5.0 LY

 5 LY = 5.0 pc

 5 pc = 1.543e+17 m

 5 pc = 5.0 km

 5 pc = 5.0 AU

 5 pc = 5.0 LY

 5 pc = 5.0 pc
```

I don't see how/why the two implementations are different. I'm guess-assuming that it has something to with the order that dictionary comprehensions count elements. But I'm not even sure if this is correct. Can someone help me understand why these two methods do not have the same output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexing is off

> ```
> @property
> def first_distance_conversion_factors(self):
>     res = {}
>     res['m'] = dict(zip(self.base_units, self.base_values))
>     for outer_key in self.base_units:
>         if outer_key != 'm':
>             res[outer_key] = {inner_key : value / res['m'][inner_key]   # outer_key here 
>                               for inner_key, value in res['m'].items()}
>     return res
> ```

Using:

```
@property
def first_distance_conversion_factors(self):
    res = {}
    res['m'] = dict(zip(self.base_units, self.base_values))
    for outer_key in self.base_units: 
        if outer_key != 'm':
            res[outer_key] = {inner_key : value / res['m'][outer_key] 
                              for inner_key, value in res['m'].items()}
    return res
```

with:

```
UC = UnitConversions()
distance = 5

for original_unit in UC.base_units:
    for prime_unit in UC.base_units:
        res = UC.first_convert_distance(distance, original_unit, prime_unit)
        print('{} {} = {} {}'.format(distance, original_unit, res, prime_unit), 
              end = " ..... ")
        res = UC.second_convert_distance(distance, original_unit, prime_unit)
        print('{} {} = {} {}'.format(distance, original_unit, res, prime_unit))
```

prints:

```
5 m = 5 m ..... 5 m = 5 m
5 m = 0.005 km ..... 5 m = 0.005 km
5 m = 3.342245989304813e-11 AU ..... 5 m = 3.342245989304813e-11 AU
5 m = 5.284853609555015e-16 LY ..... 5 m = 5.284853609555015e-16 LY
5 m = 1.6202203499675955e-16 pc ..... 5 m = 1.6202203499675955e-16 pc
5 km = 5000 m ..... 5 km = 5000 m
5 km = 5.0 km ..... 5 km = 5.0 km
5 km = 3.342245989304813e-08 AU ..... 5 km = 3.342245989304813e-08 AU
5 km = 5.284853609555016e-13 LY ..... 5 km = 5.284853609555016e-13 LY
5 km = 1.6202203499675955e-13 pc ..... 5 km = 1.6202203499675955e-13 pc
5 AU = 748000000000.0 m ..... 5 AU = 748000000000.0 m
5 AU = 748000000.0 km ..... 5 AU = 748000000.0 km
5 AU = 5.0 AU ..... 5 AU = 5.0 AU
5 AU = 7.906140999894303e-05 LY ..... 5 AU = 7.906140999894303e-05 LY
5 AU = 2.4238496435515228e-05 pc ..... 5 AU = 2.4238496435515228e-05 pc
5 LY = 4.7305e+16 m ..... 5 LY = 4.7305e+16 m
5 LY = 47305000000000.0 km ..... 5 LY = 47305000000000.0 km
5 LY = 316209.89304812835 AU ..... 5 LY = 316209.89304812835 AU
5 LY = 5.0 LY ..... 5 LY = 5.0 LY
5 LY = 1.5328904731043422 pc ..... 5 LY = 1.5328904731043422 pc
5 pc = 1.543e+17 m ..... 5 pc = 1.543e+17 m
5 pc = 154300000000000.0 km ..... 5 pc = 154300000000000.0 km
5 pc = 1031417.1122994652 AU ..... 5 pc = 1031417.1122994652 AU
5 pc = 16.309058239086777 LY ..... 5 pc = 16.309058239086777 LY
5 pc = 5.0 pc ..... 5 pc = 5.0 pc
```

---

Probably better for testing (if you do not write *real* tests):

```
for original_unit in UC.base_units:
    for prime_unit in UC.base_units:
        m1 = UC.first_convert_distance(distance, original_unit, prime_unit)
        m2 = UC.second_convert_distance(distance, original_unit, prime_unit)
        assert m1 == m2, f"{m1} != {m2} for {original_unit} to {prime_unit}"
```

.. this will Issue only output if something is wrong

Comment: Thanks, fixing that index error fixed my problem. Out of curiosity, do you think this is a good way to go about a problem like this, or would you recommend a different approach?

Comment: @allthemike I would not spend the time to do version1 if version2 works. V2 is easier to understand, there is not much "gain" in terms of "less lines" coded - I probably would do a real test or use assertions instead of parsing text outptu myself. See edit. All in all I would probably not use instance methods here - each conversion creates the dictionary _throw away style_ anew. Probably better to create it only once (TL;DR: create class variable dict with None, check if class var is None, if so create dict else just use it).

Comment: @allthe V1 is better if you adjust the units afterwards because you only need to edit one place and the others are computed from it - wich maybe would make me do it none the less - normally you only need one converion though - and can make up the calculations from 'm' on the fly without persisting them into own lookups - as always ... it depends :D